# Why doesn't my View disappear after removing from parent ViewController in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I am making an app using sprite kit, so my scenes/views are all SKView optionals. However I am trying to allow the user to upload/take photos, and everything works well on that end. However, after the user selects a photo, my image view controller somehow gets animated again, and the scene that I was in before no longer enables interaction, so it is basically frozen. I am confused why this happens... this is what I have tried so far:

Scene that I am in when giving option for selecting a photo

```
 func photoToController(sender: UIButton){ 
    var button = sender
    let controller = imageViewController()
    sender.superview?.removeFromSuperview()
    view?.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.pickPhoto(sender: &image, button: &imageUploader,       buttonsender: &button)

}
```

ViewController that allows user to deal with photo library/camera

```
 class imageViewController : UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var image = UIImageView()
var Abutton = UIButton()
var takingPhoto = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("imgviewloaded")
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("image view is animated")
}

func pickPhoto(sender: inout UIImageView, button: inout UIButton, buttonsender: inout UIButton) {
    let types = [UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary,UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera]
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(types[buttonsender.tag]) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = types[buttonsender.tag]
        if buttonsender.tag == 1 {takingPhoto = true
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        } else {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        }
        image = sender
        Abutton = button
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.removeFromParentViewController()
}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
   image.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    if takingPhoto{image.contentMode = .scaleToFill}
    if   image.image == info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as?      UIImage{
    savedPhotos.saveNewPhoto(newPhoto : image.image!)
    }
    image.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    Abutton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.removeFromParentViewController()

}





}
```

Comment: Why are you instantiating an `imageViewController()` *every time* a button is clicked?

Comment: it was just the first solution i came up with that worked, and i figured i would remove it right after. I never messed much with view controllers, is that not a proper way that it works?

Comment: That's almost certainly *not* what you want.

Comment: well how would i go around that way, because i thought i needed the controller to be initialized so i can access the photos/camera